# Plotly express treemap background color

Tags: python, plotly, treemap, streamlit, plotly-express

I'm using plotly express `treemap`, I have different things to plot with preassigned colors. **When there is no coincidence between both of the colors in the same section or subplot, the color of the section is assigned automatically to orange. How can I change that change that orange background color to another, for example white?**

Example of the code, here "un", "conjunto" and "activo" are the sections of the treemap:

```
fig = px.treemap(df_prueba,
        path=[px.Constant(ruta),'un','conjunto','activo'], 
        color='color',
        color_discrete_map={'rojo':'red', 'verde':'#00b200', 'amarillo':'yellow',
            'gris':'#989898', 'azul':'blue', 'blanco':'white'},
        width=1400, height=700)

fig.update_traces(root_color='lightgrey')
        
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `color_discrete_sequence=[new_color]` setted before calling `color_discrete_map` solved the problem.It changes that random orange color to a new color for ex: `new_color = "purple"` .